# Arch linux: set copy/paste/cut shortcuts

Tags: arch-linux, i3, clipboard, x-server, xclip

I would like to set custom keyboard shortcuts for using clipboard. I would like to change it from:

> **Copy**: `ctrl + c` in programs, `ctrl + shift + c` in terminal
> **Paste**: `ctrl + v` in programs, `ctrl + shift + v` in terminal
> **Cut**: `ctrl + x` in programs, does not work properly in terminal

To:

> **Copy**: `Win + c` everywhere
> **Paste**: `Win + v` everywhere
> **Cut**: `Win + x`  everywhere

How can I achive this ?
Thank you for your help

PS: I am using: Arch linux, xserver, i3wm, xclip, alacritty

Comment: Each program interacts on its own manner with the clipboard (and terminal emulators are especially picky), so an universal solution is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `bindsym` is for associating a key with a command and that `$mod` is a variable that stores your picked special key (you had to choose between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd><sup>(1)</sup>).

So, let's go:

1. Be sure you have installed `wl-clipboard`, it works on Wayland (which is the default server for i3). On Arch Linux you can ensure its installation with this command:

   ```shell
   sudo pacman -S wl-clipboard --needed -y
   ```
2. Lets edit the i3 config file, default at `~/.config/i3/config`
3. Add the following lines for both copy and paste<sup>(2)</sup>:

   ```
   bindsym $mod+c exec wl-copy
   bindsym $mod+v exec wl-paste
   ```
4. Save it

About the 'cut' function: maybe you could do something like

```
bindsym $mod+x exec wl-copy ERASE
```

where `ERASE` may be a function which deletes the chosen text after its copying. Of course that last one **does not work** as it is! We need to think in a way to replace `ERASE`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> We don't say <kbd>Win</kbd> on Linux, but <kbd>Super</kbd>. It's the same key by the way.

<sup>(2)</sup> The combo `$mod+v` is used by default to split vertically, I recommend to use *paste* with `$mode+p` or something else.